# Print all amino acids with equal frequency in a given sequence

Tags: python, counter

I'm trying to print for the user the most common amino acid that appears in their  protein sequence (ex.: if user inputs AHEHD, the most common AA is H, which appears 2 times)

Currently, I use Counter and most.common(), which works in most cases:

```
sequence=input("\n" + "\033[1;34;40mHello, and Welcome! Please enter your sequence:").upper()
AA_count=Counter(sequence) 
AA_mostfrequent=AA_count.most_common(1)
```

When printing:

```
for key, value in AA_mostfrequent:
                print("\n",key, "\033[1;35;40mis the most common amino acid in your sequence, appearing", value, "time(s)!", sep=" ")
```

However, say I have a sequence with certain AA appearing just as frequently as the others (ex.: ADEH or AAAAADEEEEE).

In this case, the program will choose arbitrarily any one of the AA to print. (ex.: using ADEH, it will say only D appears the most in my sequence, appearing 1 time)

I won't know how many times each AA appears in a given sequence. The rule is that I can provide whichever valid protein sequence is desired, at whatever length, so long as its stated which of the amino acids is(are) the most common.

*** for finding the frequency of each AA:

```
AA_total=len(sequence)
for key, value in sorted(AA_count.items()):
              print(key,value/AA_total, sep=":")
```

Comment: You need to identify what that top frequency is.  Then locate and print each element with that frequency.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: *using ADEH, it will say only D appears the most in my sequence, appearing 1 time* - what do you want your program to say instead?

Comment: I already can find the frequency of each amino acid. I'll put the code into my question now.

Comment: For the example with ADEH, instead of saying that A or D or E or H appears 1 time, I want it to say that A,D,E,H all appear the most frequently (1 time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the count of the most common AA, you can loop over the counter and select the ones with the highest count:

```
AA_count=Counter('GATTACAT') 
AA_most_common=AA_count.most_common(1)
most_common = [AA for AA, ct in AA_count.items() if ct == AA_most_common[0][1]]

print(most_common)
>>> ['A', 'T']
```

Comment: Thank you!  What exactly does it signify when you say AA_most_common[0][1]]?

Comment: Counter.most_common() returns a list of tuples, from the most common to the least: [(‘A’, 3), (‘G’, 3),...]. The first index [0] gives you the first element of that list (i.e. the most common, (‘A’, 3)), the second [1] gives you the second element of the first tuple, i.e 3, which is the max count.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get list of all acids that have the same, most frequent occurance, you can use:

```
[(acid, cnt) for acid, cnt in AA_count.items() if cnt == AA_count.most_common(1)[0][1]]
```

result of this expression (which you would assign to `AA_mostfrequent`) is of same format as you currently expect -- list of acid-count pairs.

Explanation:

```
[(acid, cnt) for                  # 4) acid-cnt pair that satisfies those conditions will be in result
acid, cnt in AA_count.items()     # 1) you loop over all pairs of acid-count
if cnt ==                         # 2) and take only those pairs, where cnt part is equal to
    AA_count.most_common(1)       # 3)result of (list of) 1 most common acid-cnt pair
        [0]                       # 3.1)from this list you take the only element
            [1]]                  # 3.2)from this element (acid-cnt pair) only cnt part
```